# Agrupacion campos en SQL

Tags: sql

Tengo un archivo con los campos **cliente1, Unidades_Vendidas1, cliente2, Unidades_Vendidas2** requiero un SQL que agrupe los clientes en una columna, y totalice las unidades_vendidas. Realice Un SQL con UNION ALL pero no realizo lo que deseaba.

- No usar instrucciones Pivot.
- Debe ser SQL simple.

> Ejemplo:

```
   cliente1     Unidades_Vendidas1   Cliente2      Unidades_Vendidas2
     José              12              Pablo             12              
     Pablo             10              Pablo              5              
     Eduardo            5              José              20             
     José              10              Pablo              3
     José              10              Eduardo            8
     Eduardo           10              Jose               6
```

> SQL Resultado

```
Cliente    Unidades_Vendidas
 Eduardo           23
 José              58
 Pablo             30
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Una publicación que simplemente dice: "este es mi ejercicio, resuélvanlo", no es bien recibida. Es mejor que incluyas el contexto (usa el botón [edit] para hacer cambios en tu pregunta): incluye que intentaste/investigaste y también cual es el problema puntual que tuviste. Demuestra algo que nos indique que formas parte de la experiencia de aprender a solucionar tu problema.

Comment: ¿Por qué alguien querría usar instrucciones pivot para hacer eso? Es como decir que no debes usar la desviación estándar para esto. El hecho de que pidas ayuda, parece indicar que no has comprendido el problema y por lo tanto no logras llegar a la solución. Trata de encontrar que tienes que hacer, explicarlo e imaginar como lo harías sin usar SQL. Traducir eso a SQL es más fácil.

Answer (score 3):

Lo primero es "separar" los campos de cliente1 y cliente2 y sus respectivas unidades para luego poder agruparlas.

Puedes hacerlo con 2 `SELECT` y utilizando un `UNION ALL`.

Una vez que tienes los datos normalizados, debería bastar con un `GROUP BY` y un `SUM` para obtener la suma de las unidades.

Suponiendo que la table se llame **VENTAS**, debería bastar consuna SQL como esta:

```
SELECT CLIENTE, sum(UNIDADES)
FROM (
Select cliente1 CLIENTE, unidades_vendidas1 UNIDADES from Ventas
union all
Select cliente2 CLIENTE, unidades_vendidas2 UNIDADES from Ventas
) Ventas GROUP BY CLIENTE
```

Comment: porque union all y no solo union?

Comment: Porque UNION elimina duplicados y UNION ALL solo junta los conjuntos de datos

Comment: Correcto lo comentado por @luis-cazares. Si no utilizas el UNION ALL verás que no salen todas las unidades.

Comment: si así es se requiere UNION ALL para que la agrupación sume todos los registros. Ya he realizado la practica y me resulto favorablemente. Muchas gracias Sr. German Esteves, por su gran colaboración y ayuda.